# friend declaration declares a non-template function

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend, specialization

I have a base Class akin to the code below.  I'm attempting to overload << to use with cout.
However, g++ is saying:

```
base.h:24: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Base<T>*)’ declares a non-template function
base.h:24: warning: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) -Wno-non-template-friend disables this warning
```

I've tried adding <> after << in the class declaration / prototype.  However, then I get it `does not match any template declaration`.  I've been attempting to have the operator definition fully templated (which I want), but I've only been able to get it to work with the following code, with the operator manually instantiated.

base.h

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Base<T> *e);
};
```

base.cpp

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Base<int> *e) {
    out << e->data;
return out;
}
```

I want to just have this or similar in the header, base.h:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Base<T> *e);
};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Base<T> *e) {
    out << e->data;
return out;
}
```

I've read elsewhere online that putting <> between << and () in the prototype should fix this, but it doesn't.  Can I get this into a single function template?

Comment: That's exactly the problem solved by Dan Saks' ["Making New Friends" idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Making_New_Friends). _(Sorry for the late comment.)_

Comment: I have linked to another question with an answer that goes into detail explaining *why* the suggested fixes are necessary/work

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Base<T>& e);
```

To:

```
template<class T>
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Base<T>& e);
```

Comment: So I didn't believe you, but this works.  However, I can't use `T` because it `shadows` the already existing `T` of the class template.

Comment: Does GCC give you a warning about the shadowing?

Comment: Yes, GCC gave a warning about shadowing.  I replaced T with Y and that resolved it. `error:  shadows template parm ‘class T’`

Comment: Interesting. I tested my answer with Visual Studio which doesn't have a problem with the shadowing. But I can see why GCC might spit out a warning... like you said, replacing T with another template parameter will eliminate the shadowing. Btw Ben, your solution doesn't compile in MSVC.

Comment: Mine is also rejected by Comeau.  Annoying because it's exactly the right syntax for what the OP wanted, but it apparently falls afoul of a restriction on friend functions.  +1 to you.

Comment: So operator<<(ostream&, const Base<T>&) becomes a friend of Base<S> even when S and T are distinct? I think the answer should clarify this.

Answer (score 25):

Gcc is rightly warning you. Despite it's appearances (it takes Base argument), it is not a function template.

Your class definition has a non-template declaration of the friend function (without the template), but the friend function definition later on is a function template (i.e. starts with template..).

Also your operator<< takes a Base *. This is not correct. It should be Base const & to retain it's built-in semantics

Probably you are looking at something as below:

```
template <typename T> 
class Base { 
  public: 
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Base<T> const &e){
       return out;
    }; 
}; 

int main(){
   Base<int> b;
   cout << b;
}
```

If you want fully templated, then this is probably what you want. But I am not sure how much useful this is over the previous one. Since the lookup involves ADL, you will never be able to resolve to any condition where T is not equal to U (as long as the call is from a context not related to this class e.g. from 'main' function)

```
template <typename T>  
class Base {  
  public:  
    template<class U> friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Base<U> const &e){ 
       return out; 
    };  
};

int main(){ 
   Base<int> b; 
   cout << b; 
}
```

Comment: Well, use of the `<<` operator wouldn't ever find any instantiation with `U != T`.  A direct call potentially could though, which would just be really weird.  It would only matter if `operator <<` for `Base<U>` accessed a global variable of type `Base<T>`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Added the part 'as long as the call is from a context not related to this class e.g. from 'main' function'. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: Maybe add how to define the friend function outside the class definition, for completeness?

Comment: @Chubsdad The problem is you can't instantiate `Base` with two different template arguments like `Base<int> b; Base<float> c;` since it would make `template<class U> ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Base<U> const &)` have multiple definitions (See here: <https://godbolt.org/z/oxK59qcMW>)

Answer (score 9):

Probably what you are looking for is:

```
template <typename T>
class Base;

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream &, const Base<T>&);

template <typename T>
class Base
{
  public:
    template<>
    friend ostream& operator << <T>(ostream &, const Base<T> &);
};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< ( ostream &out, const Base<T>& e )
{
    return out << e->data;
}
```

This friends only a single instantiation of the template, the one where the operator's template parameter matches the class's template parameter.

UPDATE: Unfortunately, it's illegal.  Both MSVC and Comeau reject it.  Which raises the question of why the original error message suggested pretty much EXACTLY this approach.

Comment: The [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16) says that the `friend` line in the class declaration should have a `<>`, not a `<T>`.

Comment: And apparently you're not supposed to need the `template<>` line before it.  (No access to compiler right now, haven't tried it.)

Comment: I believe the original error message is suggesting `public: friend ostream& operator << <>(ostream &, const Base<T> &);`

Answer (score 7):

changing

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Base<T>& e);
```

to

```
friend ostream& operator << <T>(ostream& out, const Base<T>& e);
```

should work as well--I just solved an identical problem in this way.

Answer (score -1):

changing

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Base<T> *e)`
```

To

```
template<T> friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Base *e)
```

Comment: This is a fake solution. `template <T>` is in fact `template <T unnamed>` in which an unnamed non-type parameter is declared. This makes the call to this function fail because the template parameter is not provided, and therefore lookup will select the global version of `operator<<`. But this does not declare the global one as a friend of `Base`, so access of `Base`'s private members in that function is not permitted.

Comment: In fact, this has the same effect as removing that friend declaration.