# Overloading operator << in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

I'm sorry if this question has been answered allready but I have a read a lot of questions considering overloading this operator in a template class but I haven't found a particular case like mine.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; 
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;

template <typename T>
class Class
{
    T x;
    public:
    friend ostream& operator << (const Class<T>&, ostream& out);
};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator << (const Class<T>&, ostream& out)
{
    return (out << out.x << endl);
}

int main()
{
    Class<short> object;
    cout << object << endl;
}
```

And I get this error on last line:
Error   1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Class' (or there is no acceptable conversion) g:\ucenje\objektno orijentirano programiranje\template3\template3\main.cpp  25  1   template3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [friend declaration declares a non-template function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039817/friend-declaration-declares-a-non-template-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.`std::ostream` should be the 1st parameter of `operator<<`, so

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator << (const Class<T>&, ostream& out)
```

should be

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Class<T>& c)
```

2.You defined `operator<<` as a template function, but `friend ostream& operator << (const Class<T>&, ostream& out);` points to a non-template function, you should change it to

```
friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream& out, const Class<T>& c);
```

And add some forward declarations before the declaration of the class:

```
template <typename T>
class Class;
template <typename T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Class<T>& c);
```

[LIVE1](http://rextester.com/CDTC59101)

Or you can define `operator<<` as non-template function inside the definition of class.

```
template <typename T>
class Class
{
    T x;
    public:
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Class<T>& c)
    {
        out << c.x << endl;
        return out;
    }
};
```

[LIVE2](http://rextester.com/ZKAJLH20820)

Comment: @Scarass No. `operator<<` must be a non-member function.

Comment: @Scarass No, it's true for non-template class too. Note `operator<<` must take `ostream` as its first argument, and you can think that the member function will always take the object as its 1st argument (as `this` pointer).

Answer (score 4):

The arguments to the `operator<<` functions have been switched, it should be e.g

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Class<T>&1);
```

The left-hand side of all binary operators is always the first argument, and the right-hand side is the second argument.