# Friend declares a non-template function even though it resides in templated class (only gcc)

Tags: c++, templates, friend, forward-declaration, shadowing

The following example compiles BUT gcc warns me that the friend declaration is in fact not a templated function. I don't understand what exactly I'm supposed to change. Clang and MSVC accept this code without any issues.

In this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039817/friend-declaration-declares-a-non-template-function) question it is implied that you're supposed to put `template <typename T>` in front of the in-class friend declaration, but then gcc complains about shadowing T.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:17,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:17,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:17,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:17,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A/*+header.hpp+*/%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+entity%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aauto+create_entity()+-%3E+std::shared_ptr%3Centity%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+entity%0A%7B%0A++++//+template+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0A++++friend+auto+create_entity()+-%3E+std::shared_ptr%3Centity%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A/*+impl.cpp+*/%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aauto+create_entity()+-%3E+std::shared_ptr%3Centity%3CT%3E%3E+%7B%0A++++return+std::make_shared%3Centity%3CT%3E%3E()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++create_entity%3Cint%3E()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.59791122715404,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.40208877284596,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

/* header.hpp */

template <typename T>
class entity;

template <typename T>
auto create_entity() -> std::shared_ptr<entity<T>>;

template <typename T>
class entity
{
    // template <typename T>
    friend auto create_entity() -> std::shared_ptr<entity<T>>;
};

/* impl.cpp */

template <typename T>
auto create_entity() -> std::shared_ptr<entity<T>> {
    return std::make_shared<entity<T>>();
}

int main()
{
    create_entity<int>();
}
```

Warning:

```
<source>:16:41: warning: friend declaration 'std::shared_ptr<entity<T> > create_entity()' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
   16 |     friend auto create_entity() -> std::shared_ptr<entity<T>>;
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:41: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add '<>' after the function name here)
```

How do I resolve this issue (for gcc)?

Comment: Your function template doesn't access anything private. Try it, then Clang and MSVC will tell you what they really think.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Indeed. So that's a fake friend then? How to make it a real one?

Comment: You found a duplicate already. It says what's the problem and what to do. It also addresses the shadowing, if one reads *all* the answers and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers used for template parameters may not be re-used inside the template for any other purpose. In other words, they may not be shadowed.

If you want any `create_entity<U>` to be a friend of `entity<T>`, change the inner `T` to `U`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto create_entity() -> std::shared_ptr<entity<T>>;

template <typename T>
struct entity
{
    template <typename U>
    friend auto create_entity() -> std::shared_ptr<entity<U>>;
};
```

If you want only `create_entity<T>` to be a friend of `entity<T>`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto create_entity() -> std::shared_ptr<entity<T>>;

template <typename T>
struct entity
{
    friend auto create_entity<T>() -> std::shared_ptr<entity<T>>;
};
```