# Declare templated function as friend when it partially depends on class- and on custom template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, friend

As a continuation to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75169730/friend-declares-a-non-template-function-even-though-it-resides-in-templated-clas?noredirect=1#comment132647861_75169730), I'm now in the situation where I want to declare a function as a friend that depends on a mix of class template parameters (`R`) AND additional template parameters (`Cb`). How do I specify this correctly within class context? My naive approach doesn't seem to work:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:40,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:40,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:40,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:40),source:%27%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfuture%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Fn,+typename+R,+typename...+Args%3E%0Aconcept+invocable_r+%3D+std::is_invocable_r%3CR,+Fn,+Args...%3E::value%3B%0A%0A/*+header.hpp+*/%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+entity%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+R,+invocable_r%3CR%3E+Cb%3E%0Aauto+create_entity(Cb%26%26+fn)+-%3E+std::shared_ptr%3Centity%3CR%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+R%3E%0Astruct+entity%0A%7B%0A++++template+%3Cinvocable_r%3CR%3E+Cb%3E%0A++++entity(Cb%26%26+fn)%0A++++++++:+fn_%7B+std::move(fn)+%7D%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%0A++++//+***************+Q+***************%0A++++//+How+to+match+this+declaration+to+the+outside+declaration%3F%0A%0A++++template%3Cinvocable_r%3CR%3E+Cb%3E%0A++++friend+auto+create_entity%3CR%3E(Cb%26%26+fn)+-%3E+std::shared_ptr%3Centity%3CR%3E%3E%3B%0A%0A++++//+***************+/Q+***************%0A%0A++++std::packaged_task%3CR()%3E+fn_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A/*+impl.cpp+*/%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+R,+invocable_r%3CR%3E+Cb%3E%0Aauto+create_entity(Cb%26%26+fn)+-%3E+std::shared_ptr%3Centity%3CR%3E%3E+%7B%0A++++return+std::make_shared%3Centity%3CR%3E%3E(std::forward%3CCb%3E(fn))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++create_entity%3Cint%3E(%5B%5D%7B+printf(%22Hello%22)%3B+return+10%3B+%7D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.59791122715404,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.40208877284596,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename Fn, typename R, typename... Args>
concept invocable_r = std::is_invocable_r<R, Fn, Args...>::value;

/* header.hpp */

template <typename T>
class entity;

template <typename R, invocable_r<R> Cb>
auto create_entity(Cb&& fn) -> std::shared_ptr<entity<R>>;

template <typename R>
struct entity
{
    template <invocable_r<R> Cb>
    entity(Cb&& fn)
        : fn_{ std::move(fn) }
    {}

    // *************** Q ***************
    // How to match this declaration to the outside declaration?

    template<invocable_r<R> Cb>
    friend auto create_entity<R>(Cb&& fn) -> std::shared_ptr<entity<R>>;

    // *************** /Q ***************

    std::packaged_task<R()> fn_;
};

/* impl.cpp */

template <typename R, invocable_r<R> Cb>
auto create_entity(Cb&& fn) -> std::shared_ptr<entity<R>> {
    return std::make_shared<entity<R>>(std::forward<Cb>(fn));
}

int main()
{
    create_entity<int>([]{ printf("Hello"); return 10; });
}
```

Error:

```
<source>:28:17: error: invalid use of template-id 'create_entity<R>' in declaration of primary template
   28 |     friend auto create_entity<R>(Cb&& fn) -> std::shared_ptr<entity<R>>;
      |
```

Comment: AFAIK, its impossible since partial specialization of functions is not allowed and you trying to create such specialization when only first template argument is defined.

Comment: @sklott Well there must be a way, I can't imaginge that this is not possible at all

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that partial specializations are not allowed in `friend` declarations (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends) (or for function templates in general).

I was able to make it work using the following steps:

1. We move the code from `create_entity` into a `struct` with a function call operator:

```
template <typename R, invocable_r<R> Cb>
struct create_entity_s {
    template<typename U = Cb>
    create_entity_s(U&& fn) : m_fn{ std::forward<U>(fn) } {}

    auto operator()() {
        auto ret = std::make_shared<entity<R>>(std::move(m_fn));
        // Test if we're really a friend by accessing a private member
        ret->_i = 5;
        return ret;
    }

    Cb m_fn;
};
```

2. Now we define `create_function` as follows, returning an instance of the above `struct`:

```
template <typename R, invocable_r<R> Cb>
auto create_entity(Cb&& fn) {
    return create_entity_s<R, Cb>{ std::forward<Cb>(fn) };
}
```

3. Change the `friend` declaration.
   Here, by using `U`, we make sure we don't partially specialize. However, this has the downside that we're now friends with every instantiation of `create_entity_s`:

```
template<typename U, invocable_r<U> Cb>
friend struct create_entity_s;
```

4. Use `create_entity` (note the parantheses at the end in order to invoke the function object):

```
create_entity<int>([]{ printf("Hello"); return 10; })();
```

Here's the full working example on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/MPKe5Me6v

I haven't been able to make it work using the function template only, but the trick with the `struct` definitely works. Also I didn't spend an extreme amount of time on this, so please excuse any imperfections, but the general principle works!

Hope this helps!